# Understanding difference between `NIntegrate` result and home-cooked Simpson's rule

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

In this question I am asking about the different results I get between `NIntegrate`-ing a function of two variables vs. "doing it myself" with my own implementation of Simpson's rule. For various "complicated" test functions, e.g.

```
testfunc = Sin[#1]^2 Cos[#2]^2 Exp[-#1^2/100 - #2^2/144]/(Abs[#1 - #2] + 0.01) &
```

the `NIntegrate` of this agrees very well with my home-cooked integrator. But in the application I'm working on, the results differ significantly. I need help to understand this. What follows might seem complicated/long but I've included everything so that a) you can just copy-paste it and it will work, and b) I cannot seem reproduce the problem for a simpler integrand.

The **reason** I have tried by own home-cooked integrator is that I want to integrate as below for many different values of `en`, and so I am willing to sacrifice a few per cent accuracy for speed. However, I seem to be sacrificing way too much, see below.

I have the following basic definitions:

```
Clear[vCI]

vCI[q1_, q2_, qs_, kappa_, d_] :=

 2 Pi/(kappa (Sqrt[(q1^2 + q2^2)/2] + qs)) Exp[-Sqrt[(q1^2 + q2^2)/
       2]*d]

vCI[q1_, q2_, qs_, kappa_, 0] :=

 2 Pi/(kappa (Sqrt[(q1^2 + q2^2)/2] + qs))

Clear[spinor]

spinor[q1_, q2_, xi_, m_, vF_] :=

 With[{alpha = vF*q2, beta = q1^2/(2 m)},
  With[{en = xi Sqrt[alpha^2 + beta^2]},
   {beta + xi (en + alpha), en - alpha + xi beta}
   ]
  ]

Clear[overlap]

overlap[spinor1_, spinor2_] :=

 If[Chop[spinor1] == {0, 0} || Chop[spinor2] == {0, 0},
  0,
  (spinor1.spinor2)^2/((spinor1.spinor1) (spinor2.spinor2))
  ]

Clear[energy]

energy[q1_, q2_, xi_, m_, 
  vF_] :=
 xi Sqrt[(vF*q2)^2 + (q1^2/(2*m))^2]
```

Now I define

```
m = 0.05;
vF = 5.;

qscreen = 0.01;
kappa = 1.;
d = 0.;
eta = 0.01;
ni = 1;

q1 = 0.5;
q2 = 0.5;
xi = 1;
en = energy[q1, q2, xi, m, vF];
```

and importantly

```
SetAttributes[integrand, Listable];
integrand[q1p_, q2p_] := Re[ni*vCI[q1 - q1p, q2 - q2p, qscreen, kappa, d]^2*
 overlap[spinor[q1, q2, xi, m, vF], 
   spinor[q1p, q2p, 1, m, vF]]/(en - 
    energy[q1p, q2p, 1, m, vF] + I eta)]
```

A plot of the integrand in the interesting region:

```
Plot3D[
 integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}
 , PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Looks fairly tame, except perhaps around `q2p == 0`. I'll talk more about this later.

We can integrate it:

```
NIntegrate[
 integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}]
(* 5.46624 + 0. I *)
```

**NB:** Not really sure why there is a complex part here (even though it's zero) because `Re` should give a purely real result even for approximate complex input.

Ok, now to the home-cooked integrator using Simpson's rule:

```
simpsonIntegrate[f_][q1pmin_, q1pmax_, q2pmin_, q2pmax_, numPoints_] :=

  Block[{a = q1pmin, b = q1pmax, c = q2pmin, d = q2pmax, n = numPoints,
   h, k, range, q1even, q1odd, q2even, q2odd},
  h = (b - a)/(2 n);
  k = (d - c)/(2 n);
  range = Range[2*n - 1];
  q1even = (a + h*range)[[2 ;; ;; 2]];
  q1odd = (a + h*range)[[1 ;; ;; 2]];
  q2even = (c + k*range)[[2 ;; ;; 2]];
  q2odd = (c + k*range)[[1 ;; ;; 2]];

  h*k/9.*(
    f[a, c] + f[a, d] + f[b, c] + f[b, d] +
     4.*Total[
       f[a, q2odd] + f[b, q2odd] + f[q1odd, c] + f[q1odd, d]] +
     2.*Total[
       f[a, q2even] + f[b, q2even] + f[q1even, c] + f[q1even, d]] +
     16.*Total[Map[Total[f[#, q2odd]] &, q1odd]] +
     8.*(Total[Map[Total[f[#, q2odd]] &, q1even]] + 
        Total[Map[Total[f[#, q2even]] &, q1odd]]) +
     4.*Total[Map[Total[f[#, q2even]] &, q1even]]
    )
  ]
```

The formula is taken from [here](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/SimpsonsRule2DMod.html). I'm using the listability as much as I can, which is the reason for the `Map[Total[...]]` stuff. Using the testing function above gives

```
NIntegrate[testfunc[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -12, 12}]
(* 32.1532 *)
simpsonIntegrate[testfunc][-10, 10, -12, 12, 100]
(* 32.3869 *)
```

and improving if I increase the last argument to `simpsonIntegrate`. But look:

```
simpsonIntegrate[integrand[#1, #2] &][-0.18, 0.18, -0.21, 0.21, 200]
(* 4.52673 *)
```

This is a deviation of 20% from `NIntegrate`! Increasing the number of gridpoints per dimension to 1000 does not help. Why this discrepancy?

I first assumed it had something to do with the line `q2p == 0` as mentioned before. We can make this go away:

```
SetAttributes[integrand2, Listable];
integrand2[q1p_, q2p_] := integrand[q1p, q2p]*Boole[Abs[q2p] > 0.02]
```

A plot:
[image]

Now there definitely shouldn't be a problem, right? Wrong:

```
NIntegrate[
 integrand2[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}]
(* 4.9732 + 0. I *)
simpsonIntegrate[integrand2[#1, #2] &][-0.18, 0.18, -0.21, 0.21, 200]
(* 4.11283 *)
```

Still 20% off... Why?

**FINAL NOTE VERSION 2**

In the end I would like to increase the range of integration, but the integrand becomes nastier. I've changed `qscreen` to 1 here:

```
Plot3D[
 integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18/0.2, 0.18/0.2}, {q2p, -0.21/0.2, 
  0.21/0.2}
 , AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

I also need to do this integral for many different values of `en`, so if I can get a quick result that is consistently no more than 2-5% wrong, I would be happy with that accuracy.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to use a polynomial method like Simpson's directly on a discontinuous function (even if the discontinuities are at the derivatives and not the function itself); split at the discontinuities first, and then integrate each piece. FWIW, an easier way to do Simpson's would be to use `Interpolation[]` with `InterpolationOrder -> 2`, and then `Integrate[]` the resulting function.

Comment: @J.M. That makes sense, but in the case of `integrand2` shouldn't Simpson's then **overestimate** the result, i.e. give a small contribution when the function drops to zero instead of nothing? Also, the error should be smaller and smaller still for finer mesh, right?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, as you've seen, things can get pathological. ;) I'll try to get a look later.

Comment: @J.M., I tried the `Interpolation` trick like you suggested and it gave a _very good_ result, 5.46775. How can that be? Is there an error in my `simpsonIntegrate` after all?

Comment: Huh. Then yes, it's your routine that's apparently pathological. :| Did you test your integrator first on "easy" functions?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, and even "hard" ones, like `testfunc`. The first thing I did was a simple Gaussian, runs fine. Can you check my routine on your end for some lame function, or `testfunc`? Might have some `Clear`ing to do here, but can't do it right now...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Do you want the answers to use that particular Mathematica definition of the Simpson rule, or using other more general/convenient Simpson rule definitions would work for you?

Comment: @AntonAntonov, as long as I can choose the number of grid points and it works for my integrand, any definition is most welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

What is observed for `testfunc` and `integrand2` is explained with the use of adaptive sampling, symbolic processing, and singularity handlers by `NIntegrate`. The home-cooked Simpson integration strategy in the question is too simple for these integrands. For the function `integrand` it seems that only the adaptive sampling gives the advantage of `NIntegrate`.

```
Needs["Integration`NIntegrateUtilities`"]

Plot3D[integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}]
```

[image]

Here are the integral estimates for different precision goal and initial region partitionings:

```
t = MapThread[{#1, #2, 
     FullForm@
      NIntegrate[
       integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}, 
       MinRecursion -> #1, PrecisionGoal -> #2]} &, {Join[
     Range[1, 6], {8, 9}], Join[ConstantArray[6, 6], {12, 12}]}];
TableForm[t, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"MinRecursion", "PrecisionGoal", 
    "Estimate"}}]
```

[image]

Here are the sampling points with the default `NIntegrate` options:

```
NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
 NIntegrate[integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}]
```

[image]

Compare with the sampling points of a 2D Cartesian rule made with 1D rule like `Trapezoidal` (analogous to using `simpsonIntegrate` in the question):

```
NIntegrateSamplingPoints@
 NIntegrate[
  integrand[q1p, q2p], {q1p, -0.18, 0.18}, {q2p, -0.21, 0.21}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
    "SingularityHandler" -> None, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"}]
```

[image]

The sampling points of the last integration are too few to get a good estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the nice visualization of the problem. But even this very simple, trapezoidal `NIntegrate` gives 5.46646, which is **much** better than my home-cooked thing. And this uses 9x9 points, while I tried 1000x1000! There must be something else wrong with my `simpsonIntegrate`, but I can't see it!

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Your question prompted me to post and answer the question ["How to implement custom integration rules for use by NIntegrate"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118324/34008) (using the Simpson rule).

Comment: I will read it carefully! Great effort. I have added some notes as to why I created my own integrator in the OP. Since vanilla `NIntegrate` just works, I will probably use it in the final calculation of things. For now though, it is too slow for me to explore different `en`, also integrate over the fixed `q1, q2` in my code etc. So I need something faster, but I'm not willing to miss by as much as 20% :P

Comment: I forgot to mention that ["TrapezoidalRule"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#618158740) uses [Romberg quadrature](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#101738258) by default. So you might consider `"RombergQuadrature" -> False` when doing comparisons.