# NIntegrate of a vector-valued InterpolatingFunction gives "not numerical"

Tags: numerical-integration

If I construct a vector-valued InterpolatingFunction, say with

```
f = Interpolation[{{0, {1,1}}, {1, {0,0}}, {2, {0,1}}, {3, {1,0}}}]
```

plotting the result works just fine.  For example,

```
ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

draws a letter "alpha" in the plane.  And, as Feyre pointed out, calling Integrate also works fine, with

```
Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

returning `{3/4, 3/2}`.  But Integrate can't deal with more complicated situations, returning unevaluated for even such simple variants as

```
Integrate[2 f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

More complicated cases can be handled numerically with NIntegrate, as long as the thing being integrated is a scalar.  For example,

```
NIntegrate[f[t].f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

returns `1.78214`.  But if I try to NIntegrate a vector-valued InterpolatingFunction, even just:

```
NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

version 10.0.2 of Mathematica gives me the error message:

```
NIntegrate::inum: Integrand 
  InterpolatingFunction[{{0,3}},{5,3,0,{4},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,
   {},{},False},{{0,1,2,3}},
   {{{0,0}},{{1,1}},{{1,0}},{{0,1}}},{Automatic}][t] 
   is not numerical at {t} = {0.00795732}. >>
```

In a case too complicated for Integrate, is there some way that I can convince NIntegrate to work, component by component, over such a vector?

Comment: There's always going to be a technique to find what you want, if everything else fails, just use `Table[]` and `Total[]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) to access the components separately:

```
NIntegrate[Indexed[f[t], 1], {t, 0, 3}]
NIntegrate[Indexed[f[t], 2], {t, 0, 3}]
(*
  0.75
  1.5
*)
```

`Integrate` will antidifferentiate an `InterpolatingFunction`. You can then subtract its values at the end points.

```
af = Head@Integrate[f[t], t];
af[3] - af[0]
(*  {3/4, 3/2}  *)
```

You can also [write your own integration rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118324/how-to-implement-custom-integration-rules-for-use-by-nintegrate) to plug into `NIntegrate`, but that takes a little work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. NIntegrate can only recognize number value function but not a function with list output? Seems it not looks like Integrate.

Comment: @swish47 Both `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` will integrate `func[x_] := {x^2, x^3};`. Neither will integrate `gunk[x_?NumericQ] := {x^2, x^3};`. `Integrate` has a special rule built in to integrate vector valued interpolating functions like the OP's `f[t]`, but it won't integrate other expressions with interpolating functions as the OP shows (not even scalar valued ones). `NIntegrate` does not have this special case. In my first case, `NIntegrate` maps itself to two 1-dim integrals, `NIntegrate[x^2,...]` and `NIntegrate[x^3,...]`. Basically, the `NIntegrate` rules handle only scalar functions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally understand some weird error from ``NIntergrate`` before. And is it possible to modify the definition of ``NIntegrate`` to intergrate a list value function directly but not map to 1d integral?

Comment: @swish47 It might be, since you can plug in your own methods (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118920) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118324)). I have not tried implementing a vector method. I'm not familiar with any integration rule for integrating vectors. I could only do it by applying rules for scalar functions to each coordinate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) to integrate your interpolating function:

```
f = Interpolation[{{0,{1,1}},{1,{0,0}},{2,{0,1}},{3,{1,0}}}];

NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == {0, 0}}, y[3], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> {0.75, 1.5}

Here is a more complicated integrand:

```
NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == f[x]^2 Sin[x], y[0] == {0, 0}}, y[3], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> {0.148276, 0.887794}