# FunctionInterpolation changes the Output dimensions of an InterpolatingFunction

Tags: numerics, interpolation

**Minimal example**

```
fun = (r /.NDSolve[
    {D[r[t], t] == -I (PauliMatrix[1].r[t]-r[t].PauliMatrix[1]), 
     r[0] == {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}},
     r, 
     {t, 0, 2}][[1]])
```

`fun` is the solution of a differential equation of matrices as a `InterpolatingFunction`. It has Output dimensions `{2,2}`, i.e. for each `t` it returns a two by two matrix, as it should.

If apply `FunctionInterpolation` to it, the Output dimensions change to `{2}`, i.e.

```
FunctionInterpolation[fun[t],{t,0,2}]
```

returns an `InterpolatingFunction` which returns a vector of length 2.

**Context**

I want to multiply the output `fun[t]` by a probability-distribution e.g. `PDF[NormalDistribution[1,0.1],t]` and Integrate over t around 1. To achieve this I thought, inspired by the tutorial on [Approximate Functions and Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApproximateFunctionsAndInterpolation.html), I could do something like this:

```
NIntegrate[
FunctionInterpolation[PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], t]*fun[t], {t, 0, 2}],
{t,0.8,1.2}]
```

Which fails due to *non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries...* which might but maybe not has something to do with the problem above.

I'd appreciate any comments,

Cheers

Comment: Note that `fun` already is a function interpolation.  It doesn't seem that `FunctionInterpolation` should even be considered in this case.

Comment: Related: [(77589)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77589), [(126342)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126342)

Comment: Hey @MichaelE2, thanks for your comment. In the link above, `FunctionInterpolation` is used as `FunctionInterpolation[x+sin[x^2],{x,0,1}]` where `sin` is an `InterpolatingFunction` of `Sin`, i.e. it is used to combine normal functions (`Plus`,`Power`) with an `InterpolatingFunction` which is what I want to do ultimately. The minimal example might as well include a `+t` to mirror the example better yet it has the same problem.
Cheers

Edit: The second link you provided might help me a lot later, thanks!

Comment: You may want to try other tacks like: Evaluating both as "fields" over the range. Separating the Integral into Real and Imaginary and/or separating it by "Parts" as two separate NIntegrate or N[Integrate[]] Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NDSolve` is mentioned in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81436/4999) to [NIntegrate over a list of functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77589/nintegrate-over-a-list-of-functions):

```
{fun, expectation} = {r, int} /. First@NDSolve[
     {D[r[t], t] == -I (PauliMatrix[1].r[t] - r[t].PauliMatrix[1]), 
      r[0] == {{1, 0}, {0, 0}},
      int'[t] == PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.1], t]*r[t], 
      int[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}},
     {r, int}, {t, 0, 2}];
expectation[2]
(*  {{0.296047 + 0. I, 0. + 0.445646 I}, {0. - 0.445646 I, 0.703953 + 0. I}}  *)
```