# NIntegrate a vector function without using Indexed and NDSolveValue?

Tags: numerical-integration

I encoutered an issue about integrand being non-numerical while trying to integrate a vector function using `NIntegrate` as shown below:

```
ClearAll[f, y, dummy1, dummy2];
f[s_?NumericQ] := {Sin[s], Cos[4*s]};
NIntegrate[f[s], {s, 0, 3}]
```

> NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[s] is not numerical at {s} = {0.023872}.

Of course, if I was able to directly plug in the vector itself, everything is good (this is in my scenario impossible since `f` is actually based on purely numerical results from `NIntegrate` and `NDSolveValue` - so I can only use `SetDelayed`).

I successfully used `Indexed` as a workaround and also `NDSolveValue` as mentioned in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159633/21606) and both actually solve the problem:

```
NIntegrate[{Sin[s], Cos[4*s]}, {s, 0, 3}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00767999, {1.98999, -0.134143}} *)
dummy1[s_?NumericQ] := Indexed[f[s], 1];
dummy2[s_?NumericQ] := Indexed[f[s], 2];
NIntegrate[{dummy1[s], dummy2[s]}, {s, 0, 3}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00453236, {1.98999, -0.134143}} *)
NDSolveValue[{y'[s] == f[s], y[0] == {0, 0}}, y[3], {s, 0, 3}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00260897, {1.98999, -0.134143}} *)
```

Surely, I do have a working solution now. But I wonder if it is somehow still possible to *just* use `NIntegrate` with adjusted options in order to avoid `Indexed` (may become annoying for high dimensions) and `NDSolveValue` (I noticed for some dummy integrands `f[s]`, there was already a factor of 5 in runtime between the simple `NIntegrate` and `NDSolveValue` approach)?

**UPDATE**: Another reason why I possibly prefer `NIntegrate` over `NDSolveValue` is that I may potentially use something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126041) which might speed things up a lot.

Comment: Did you try to avoid `NumericQ` in your code? `f[s_] := {Sin[s], Cos[4*s]};`??

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I did now. It won't work because it will then try to plug in `f[s]` "symbolically" which is possible in the simple example in the question, but not for my real `f[s]`, unfortunately.

Comment: Essentially the same issue: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126342/nintegrate-of-a-vector-valued-interpolatingfunction-gives-not-numerical