# NIntegrate can't integrate function which returns list, but can integrate list directly

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following dummy Code

```
f[arg : {__?NumericQ}] := 2*arg;
g := f[{x, y}]
NIntegrate[g, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[f[{x, y}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Both tries yield

> NIntegrate::inum: Integrand f[{x,y}] is not numerical at {x,y} = {0.5,0.5}.

Despite

```
f[{x, y}] /. x -> 0.5 /. y -> 0.5
{1.,1.}
f[{0.5, 0.5}]
{1.,1.}
```

However, if I enter the function directly, I get the expected result

```
NIntegrate[2*{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
{1., 1.}
```

**Why does the first try fail and the last try evaluate?**

Comment: `f` evaluates to a list of numbers, and NIntegrate is expecting just a number.

Comment: @CarlWoll That is wrong, see my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(34554)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34554), [(174256)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174256). Related: [(126342)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126342).

Comment: ^ from (126342), the answer is to use `Indexed` like so `{NIntegrate[Indexed[f[{x, y}], 1], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], NIntegrate[Indexed[f[{x, y}], 2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]}` which gives `{1., 1.}`

Comment: I updated the question, to address the difference between the approaches.

Comment: @infinitezero btw you have a syntax error `;;` which is shorthand for Span.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it, this was not in my original code.

Comment: Use either `NIntegrate[#, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] & /@ g` or `NIntegrate[#, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] & /@ f[{x, y}]`

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that even with using `Evaluate`, neither `g` nor `f[{x,y}]` will evaluate without satisfying the `NumericQ` that has been imposed on `arg`. There are a number of solutions mentioned in the related links that @MichaelE2 has linked to in the comments, and other solutions offered by @flinty & @Bob Hanlon. However, if control of the function being input into `NIntegrate` is possible, you may find inspiration in the following simple solution:

```
h[arg:{__}]:=2*arg;
NIntegrate[h[{x,y}],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

> `{1.,1.}`

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Usually, the NumericQ predicate is used because the function will not work if given nonnumerical input. In your simple example, this is not an issue, but probably in the OP usage, it is an issue.

Comment: @CarlWoll right, this is why I mention this in my answer. “If control of the function being input...” While I understand what you are saying, I don’t think I am “missing the point”—the usage of `NumericQ` here is very much well understood, and the reasons why it is not working are also well understood. I offer a simple solution which satisfies OP’s main point iterated in the title of the question. “`NIntegrate` can’t integrate function which returns list, but can integrate list directly”. This is shown, clearly, to not be so, as in the simple solution offered in my answer.

Comment: Your solution works because NIntegrate (while HoldAll) evaluates the integrand symbolically before computing the result. Your approach is no different than using `NIntegrate[2 {x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll right. Exactly! Except that it uses a defined function? At any rate, we know we can define a function that returns a list, and then integrate it.