# Integrating a Interpolation function with domain {0,1} and output dimension >1: I don't understand this behavior--can anyone help me out?

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation

My goal is to integrate the last dimension of the output of an Interpolation function. I am getting behavior that I don't understand  (*note to readers, I've pasted all the code without comments at the bottom so you can copy and paste just once*):

Data to demonstrate, not real problem:

```
data = Table[{t, RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, 12]}, {t, 0, 1, .01}];
intFunc = Interpolation[data]
```

This works as I would expect:

```
Integrate[intFunc[t], {t, 0, 1}]
Last[Integrate[intFunc[t], {t, 0, 1}]]
```

*A priori,* this didn't:

```
NIntegrate[intFunc[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

So, force the integrand to be numerical:

```
ifunN[t_?NumericQ] := Last[intFunc[t]]
NIntegrate[ifunN[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

OK, I get an extra warning, but the result is fine (puzzled why Integrate is doing a different job than NIntegrate though).

**Here is the behavior that really puzzles me:**

```
Integrate[Last[intFunc[t]], {t, 0, 1}]  (*returns 1/2 ???*)
NIntegrate[Last[intFunc[t]], {t, 0, 1}]  (*returns 0.5 which is consistent, but why?*)
```

Let's experiment a bit to see if we can figure out where the weird result is coming from:

```
{val, {reap}} = 
  Reap[NIntegrate[Last[intFunc[t]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Last[intFunc[t]]}] ]];

ifreap = Interpolation[reap];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
```

This yields an approximation to the "expected behavior" (except for a factor of 2)

```
Integrate[
 ifreap[t], {t, InterpolatingFunctionDomain[ifreap][[1, 1]], InterpolatingFunctionDomain[ifreap][[1, 2]]}]
```

So, the experiment doesn't help me figure out the the behavior.

All Code if you want to copy-and-paste once:

```
data = Table[{t, RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, 12]}, {t, 0, 1, .01}];
intFunc = Interpolation[data]

Integrate[intFunc[t], {t, 0, 1}]
Last[Integrate[intFunc[t], {t, 0, 1}]]

NIntegrate[intFunc[t], {t, 0, 1}]


ifunN[t_?NumericQ] := Last[intFunc[t]]
NIntegrate[ifunN[t], {t, 0, 1}]

Integrate[
 Last[intFunc[t]], {t, 0, 1}]  (*returns 1/2 ???*)
NIntegrate[
 Last[intFunc[t]], {t, 0, 
  1}]  (*returns 0.5 which is consistent,but why?*)

{val, {reap}} = 
  Reap[NIntegrate[Last[intFunc[t]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, Last[intFunc[t]]}]]];

ifreap = Interpolation[reap];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];

Integrate[
 ifreap[t], {t, InterpolatingFunctionDomain[ifreap][[1, 1]], 
  InterpolatingFunctionDomain[ifreap][[1, 2]]}]
```

Comment: If I had to guess, `Integrate` is using the exact Hermite polynomial and manipulating it symbolically, while NIntegrate is evaluating it numerically. I don't know why you think 0.5 vs 1/2 is weird - NIntegrate does numerical integration, so of course it deals with machine numbers.

Comment: Note that `Last[intFunc[t]]` equals `t`, so those integrals are justing integrating `t`.  Maybe `Indexed[intFunc[t], -1]` is what you're after.

Comment: Note also that `Integrate[intFunc[t], t]` returns an antiderivative in the form of an interpolating function equal to $\int_a^t f(\tau)\,d\tau$, where $f$ is `intFunc` and $a$ is the beginning of the domain, namely `0` in this case.

Comment: @MichaelE2, Yes. You are right. Thanks. NIntegrate[Indexed[intFunc[t], -1], {t, 0, 1}] gives the correct result.  Would never have thought of using Indexed.

Comment: I consider this question answered.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126342/nintegrate-of-a-vector-valued-interpolatingfunction-gives-not-numerical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Last[intFunc[t]]` equals `t`, so the two confusing integrals are just integrating `t` from `0` to `1`, which is why one gets `1/2`.
What is needed is `Indexed[intFunc[t], -1]`, which extracts a part only when its first argument is a vector.

```
NIntegrate[Indexed[intFunc[t], -1], {t, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> (*  0.00378552  *)
> ```