# Can't get the correct answer with this Adaptive Simpson's Rule algorithm

Tags: numerical-integration, syntax

I think the mathematical portion of my algorithm is correct, but I don't really know the mathematica syntax.

How do I get the actual function to be evaluated?

Code:

```
Simpson[a_, b_, count_] := Module[{},
   Return[(b - a)/6 (f[a] + 4 f[(a + b)/2] + f[b])]];
Adaptive[a_, b_, tol_, count_] := Module[{c},
   c = (a + b)/2;
   Sab = Simpson[a, b, count];
   Sac = Simpson[a, c, count];
   Scb = Simpson[c, b, count];
   If[Abs[Sab - Sac - Scb] < tol,
    Return[Sac + Scb],
    Return[count],
    Return[Adaptive[a, c, tol/2] + Adaptive[c, b, tol/2]]];];
f[x_] = Cos[x^2];
Print["f[x] = ", f[x]];
tol1 = 0.001;
count = 0;
Print[Adaptive[0.0, 2.0, tol1, count]];
```

This ends up returning:

```
f[x] = Cos[x^2]
0
```

Comment: It'd be nicer if you could post your code in a way that people don't have to retype the whole thing. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128300) as well.

Comment: Something that strikes me as strange is your `ìf` that has three expressions within, the last of which is only returned if `Abs[Sab-Sac-Scb]` doesn't return True or False. Are you sure this is what you wanted?

Comment: I was studying a book with examples written like this, but I can't seem to get the same answers as the book.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in this expression

```
If[Abs[Sab - Sac - Scb] < tol,
  Return[Sac + Scb],
  Return[count],
  Return[Adaptive[a, c, tol/2] + Adaptive[c, b, tol/2]]];]
```

so first, you have `If[condition, expression1, expression2, expression3]` where `expression3` is only evaluated if `condition` evaluates neither to `True` or `False`. Since that shouldn't happen for a simple numerical comparison, your algorithm was always stuck Returning `count` which is initialized to 0 so your function returns 0.

Second, your `Adaptive` demands 4 arguments, you only provide three though.
Correcting that, i.e. replacing the above block by

```
If[Abs[Sab - Sac - Scb] < tol, Return[Sac + Scb], 
   Return[Adaptive[a, c, tol/2, count] + 
     Adaptive[c, b, tol/2, count]]];]
```

yields the correct result

```
f[x] = Cos[x^2]

0.461459
```

To find errors like these it can help to put some `Print`s in your function so you can see e.g. how deep you go in the recursive function or whether `Simpson` returns results that are nonsensical or not.