# Is it possible to extend the graph layout framework with our own methods?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, undocumented

The [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html) specification can take complex forms, where we can specify separate vertex layouts, edge layout and packing layouts. Often each of these takes more sub-options.

Other frameworks in Mathematica that deal with similarly complex method specifications are user-extensible.  [This is documented for `NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html), and while undocumented, [also possible for NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118324/12).

Is the graph layout framework similarly extensible?  Can we create our own vertex, edge or packing layout methods?  Can we re-use the existing methods for other problems in isolation (e.g. pack something else than graph components)?